# SSRS Report Column Reorder Column after grouping

Tags: reporting-services

This is the current output of my report

[image]

I used grouping for all the fields except 'Product Sampled'

Now I want to rearrange the column position as 'Product Sampled' as the third last one

- Doctor Code
- Name of Doctor
- POB
- Doctor Specialty
- Class
- Product Sampled
- Product detailed
- Promotional Material

Please provide a solution for this

Comment: "Please provide a solution"? You should [tell us what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) first.

Answer (score 0):

I regret doing the needful...

Why dont you simply move/drag the place holder(s) for the columns to the order you want?

Comment: How to move the placeholder? The result is in a table. Is it possible to drag the column?

Comment: Yes, you create your dataset right?  When you expand it, you see the list of columns in the dataset.  When you drag a table out onto the design surface, drag the columns onto the table in the order you want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataset . I mean first try open the existing report in the report builder and drag the column and save it. It will do the trick